# increment hex value by a certain value in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a hexadecimal variable that I want to increase its inc value by x20 in every loop.
For example for 10 rounds, **inc** value increase by 0x20 and add to the **pam** in each loop.

but now i'm getting 1060,1061,1063,1066,106a,106f,1075 etc...

```
int main() {
  int inc = 0x20;
  int pam = 0x1040;

  for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {
      inc = inc++;
      cout << pam+inc << endl;
      }
  return 0;
}
```

What I want to get is 1040, 1060, 1080, 10A0, etc.
Example;

```
Output:
pam + inc
pam + inc + inc
pam + inc + inc + inc
etc...
```

Comment: You are changing the increment value, is this what you want?  The first increment is by 0x20, then next by 0x21.

Comment: `inc++` means `inc` would +1 after this instruction. Also it equals to `inc=inc+1`. And the `inc=` in `inc=inc++` does nothing.

Comment: no I want it to increase 0x20, 0x40, 0x60, 0x80 each round. increase by 0x20 from previous loop

Comment: Then you need `inc += 0x20` since `inc++` is increase by 1.

Comment: Why not just modify `pam`?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'hex value'. Values in a computer are binary. Hex is only a representation used for printing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method to increment numbers using a **fixed** increment:

```
const int inc = 0x20;
//...
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  pam += inc;
  std::cout << "pam: " << pam << "\n";
}
```

If you can't modify `pam` then modify the increment:

```
int inc = 0x20;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    inc += 0x20;
    std::cout << (pam + inc) << endl;
}
```

Applying some math:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    std::cout << ((inc * i) + pam) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hey Thank You!, this solved my problem :)

Comment: If it does you well, click on the check mark.